# Prove that the set $[0,\infty )$ is not open.

Tags: general-topology

$U \subset \Bbb R$ is open if
$\forall x \in U,$ $\exists r\gt0$ such that $\forall y \in \Bbb R, |y-x|\lt r\Rightarrow y \in U$

Then prove that the set $[0,\infty )$ is not open by verifying the above statement is true.

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: You mean verifying the above statement is false?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $U=[0, \infty)$ and let $x$ be 0. Does this satisfy that definition?

Comment: all i can come up with is if x is zero, then | y | < r, -r < y < r.

Comment: @Tim there's -r/2 in that interval, which is not included in U.

Answer (score 0):

If $U=[0, \infty)$ is open in $\mathbb R$, then $\mathbb R-[0, \infty)=(-\infty,0)$ is closed, but it is not the case.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a useful answer. The definition of "closed" is "the complement of an open set," so this manipulation hasn't really done anything. (Yes, we could apply a different characterization of "closed" but this answer doesn't do that)